# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'MSIE'

Tags: python

After I run my Python code on a big file of only HTTP headers, it gives me the above error. Any idea what that means?

Here is a piece of the code:

```
users = output.split(' ')[1]
accesses = output.split(' ')[3]
ave_accesses = int(accesses)/int(users)
```

Basically the 'users' are users who have accessed a website and 'accesses' are the total number of accesses by the users to that site. The 'ave_accesses' gives the number of accesses to that site by an average user. I hope this is enough to clear things, if not I can explain more.

thanks a lot, Adia.

Comment: "my Python code"?  "a big file of only HTTP headers"?  No traceback.  No code. We have no clue.

Comment: I made some changes in the above post. tell me if not enough.

Comment: not enough. You should post an example data. Aside comment: you don't need to call `split` twice. `splito = output.split(); users=splito[1]; accesses = splito[3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you are trying to convert a string to an integer, and the value of the string is 'MSIE'. The traceback will have a filename near this error and the line number (e.g., /my/module.py:123). Open the file and go to the line the error occurred, you should see a call to `int()` with a parameter. That parameter is probably supposed to be a number in string form, but it's not. You probably got your parsing code a little wrong, and fields were mixed up.

To track down the problem, use `print` statements around the code to see what is not working as expected. You can also use `pdb`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your header output is garbled. It is obviously looking for a number where it is find an string MSIE (which may be the value for User-Agent).